# Unifi UAPs interfaces producing annoying out-errors in nagios/check_mk

Tags: unifi

Since I have setup some UAPs and monitor them with my check_mk server over SNMP, I get flooded (a few hundreds a day) with warnings and critical messages about out-errors on the interfaces. What are these errors (percentage varies from 0.x% - 70% and more).

Example:

```
Host:     UAP-AC-PRO-5
Alias:    UAP-AC-PRO-5
Address:  192.16...
Service:  Interface 09
Event:    OK -> CRIT
Output:   CRIT - [ath3] (up) MAC: FC:EC:DA:7E:A5:FF, speed unknown, in: 583.15 B/s, out: 300.79 B/s, out-errors: 1.31%(!!) = 0.1%
Perfdata: in=583.147261;;;0; inucast=2.596055;;;; innucast=0;;;; indisc=0;;;; inerr=0;0.01;0.1;; out=300.792955;;;0; outucast=2.512848;;;; outnucast=0;;;; outdisc=0;;;; outerr=0.033283;0.01;0.1;; outqlen=0;;;0;
```

What are these messages and what do they tell me about my WIFI setup? I notice no issues on wifi no connection drops or packet loss so I'd like to get rid of the messages.